# How can I remove the values apostrophes of my choice from a line?

Tags: c#

I want to remove in each line from specific values the apostrophes.
This is my code for writing into a text file:

```
for (int a = 0; a < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; a++)
                {

                    DataTable ExportTable = new DataTable();

                    //Debug.WriteLine(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[a].ToString());

                    string SelectLines = 
                    "SELECT Identifier,
                            TestID,
                            Description,
                            Enabled,
                            StringLimit,
                            LowLimit,
                            HighLimit,
                            LimitType,
                            Unit,
                            Parameters 
                 FROM specifications 
         where Identifier = '" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[a] + "'";
                    ExportTable = ObjSqlAccess.GetDataTableFromTable(SelectLines);

                    int rowcount = ExportTable.Rows.Count;
                    int columncount = ExportTable.Columns.Count;
                    int rw = 0;
                    int clm = 0;

                    writeText.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n[" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[a].ToString() + "]" + "\r\nCount = " + (rowcount - 1));


                    for (rw = 0; rw < rowcount - 1; rw++)
                    {

                        string test = "";
                        for (clm = 0; clm < columncount - 1; clm++)
                        {
                            test += ExportTable.Rows[rw][clm].ToString();
                            test += "','";

                        }


                        writeText.WriteLine((rw + 1) + "=(Identifier,TestID,Description,Enabled,StringLimit,LowLimit,HighLimit,LimitType,Unit,Parameters) VALUES ('" + removeThis + "')");

                    }
                    writeText.Flush();
                    writeText.Close();
                    writeText.Dispose();
```

And for instance, I want to remove the apostrophes from each line from only these values: 1, 0 , 0 before writing it to a text file. Or to be more specific, only the values that are assigned to Enable, LowLimit and HighLimit column.

Does anyone has an idea of how to proceed? I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: By apostrophes do you mean the single quote `'`?  The same one used to mark SQL strings?

Comment: Can you test in your for loop if the column requires single quotes?  If so, then just apply the single quotes to those values and just use comma as a separator.  Also you might want to look into using `string.Join`.

Comment: yes! this is my number that is in my file : '1' and this is how I want it to look like : 1

Comment: If I do not have those quotes for each value then it will not insert them into the DataTable. But those 3 columns that I have mentioned need to  have the values without the quotes.

Comment: string,join would be more or less the same as test += " ',' ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would change the way you're writing the string so it doesn't care if there are single quotes, or anything else, in the variable you pass for `VALUES`.

```
writeText.WriteLine((rw + 1) + "=(Identifier,TestID,Description,Enabled,StringLimit,LowLimit,HighLimit,LimitType,Unit,Parameters) VALUES (" + test + ")");
```

Also worth noting is I don't think your loops will work correctly. When you use a `count` in a `for` loop, the `count` is already 1-indexed. So, if you do `columnCount = ExportTable.Columns.Count;`, your loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)`. An easy way to remember is index is 0-based, but count is 1-based.

I would also use a string builder instead. Then in your loop just do a check for those columns:

```
string test = "";
                        for (clm = 0; clm < columncount; clm++)
                        {
                            StringBuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
                            sb.Append(ExportTable.Rows[rw][clm].ToString());

                            if (clm != 3 && clm != 5 && clm != 6)
                            {
                                sb.Insert(0,"'");
                                sb.Append("'");
                            }

                            test += sb;

                            if (clm != columncount - 1) // add a comma if it's not the last column
                            {
                                test += ",";
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: BTW - You might want to add a check for NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for (clm = 0; clm < columncount - 1; clm++)
    {
        DataColumn col = ExportTable.Columns[clm];
        test += ExportTable.Rows[rw][clm].ToString();
        if (col.DataType == bool || col.DataType == Int32) //Add other types that dont require single quotes to if statement
        {
            test += ",";
        }
        else
        {
            test += "','";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I do think my soluion is more generic. DrewJordan's solution will only work if the indexed column is 3,5, or 6. If that changes then it won't work. Checking the DataType would allow you to build a function that would work for a variety of different scenarios.

Comment: I do agree with you but the project I am working on is going to have those 3 columns like that. Nothing will change in my database, there will be no modifications. I will also take your example into consideration for my future projects, so thank you!